# How to organize multiple Http Functions under same Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to host multiple HttpTrigger functions under one FunctionApp. So under Functions I can have multiple HttpTrigger functions exist.

I am using FTP to connect to my server.
Below is files take are generated when I use publish option in VS 2017

[image]
and below is list of files that should be pushed on to the server to run this HttpTrigger.
[image]

[image]

**My Question is how should I organize my multiple HttpTrigger related files under wwwroot folder?**
Like should I create 2 folders under wwwroot for each trigger? I tried that but azure portal could NOT found my trigger.

Comment: the function app sdk should do it for you while packaging/publishing your function app using Visual studio. You should not need to do it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Function App(doesn't matter whether it contains multiple HttpTriggers or any other kind of triggers), has to be organized in the following fashion:

```
- bin(containing DLLs or any other kind of executables)
- FunctionA(containing its function.json)
- FunctionB(...)
- FunctionC(...)
- ...
- host.json
```

With such a setup, you should be able to use multiple functions under the same app.

Comment: I will try this. There is *.deps.json file also at same level as bin and FunctionA folder so it should stay as it is?